# Mod-Rewrite REGEX not working Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get the following working:

When a user uses a search box, the get sends the user to `www.example.com/search/?s=Query+String`

Sending the GET request is not a problem, however, grabbing it via a `RewriteRule` is. I'm not sure my REGEX is proper in this case.

```
RewriteRule ^search/\?s=(.*[^/])$ search.php?s=$1 [NC,L]
```

What needs to happen is that the `/search/?s=Query+String` Query string part has to be taken from that url and sent over to `search.php?s=Query+String` via the Rewrite Rule

Comment: Why not just move `search.php` to `search/index.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query string from request is stored in variable `%{QUERY_STRING}`. Rules use `%{REQUEST_URI}`. Just use `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^search/?$ search.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

Tested [here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).

Comment: No, that means that slash isn't required

Comment: I had forgotten about `QSA`

Comment: @VolodymyrMelnychuk - Maybe you have an idea how I can solve this question I have open?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390562/apostrophes-and-colons-in-pretty-links