# mod_rewrite does not trigger css to load

Tags: css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all requests to index.php and any %{REQUEST_URI} portion should be passed as an argument to index.php. Also, even if the %{REQUEST_URI} portion points to an existing file/directory, I still want to do the redirect. For example, there is a directory called `js` in my document root. When I access my site like `http://www.example.com/js`, then I still want to redirect to `http://www.example.com/index.php?uri=js` instead of displaying the content of the directory in a browser.

So, I added the following two lines in my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* index.php?uri=%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA]
```

But this does not work.

First, when I specify a path to an existing file, e.g. `http://www.example.com/foo.css`, it still displays a content of the file in a browser. (What I want is `http://www.example.com/index.php?uri=foo.css`) Second, when accessing a directory, e.g. `http://www.example.com/js`, then the redirect happens, but css fails to take effect and my site looks corrupted.

The good news is it works fine if I specify an arbitrary string that does not point to any files/directories in the root. I spent hours trying to debug this, but I have no clue. How would I solve my problems?

FYI, I'm using Apache 2.4.3.

Comment: Ok, the problem why my css is not loading was because I had an incorrect relative path. Basically, I changed the href attribute inside a link tag from href="style.css" to href="./style.css". But I haven't solved my other problem where exisiting files are still displayed in a browser.

Comment: This rule alone should work as you describe. You probably have other rules in .htaccess, which are before this rule.

Comment: @OlafDietsche, ok, it is not working when I do http://www.example.com/style.css. That is, the content of the css file is displayed in my browser. But it works when I do http://www.example.com/login.php. Both files exist in the document root. Is this something specific to browser I use? I use Google Chrome.

Comment: @OlafDietsche, Thanks for your help again. After I fixed the silly mistake I had, it is working correctly now. I should have checked my codes well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this following code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.php?uri=(.*)$ $1 [L]
```

I don't know if it's that you want.

Comment: That won't work, check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411898/mod-rewrite-regex-not-working-apache/15411957#15411957

Comment: @LucasWillems, Yup, it didn't work. I solved my problem. Please see comments under my question.